# Macros para tablas deshabilitadas en Access 2019

Tags: trigger, ms-access

tengo una consulta, vi un video de desencadenantes(Triggers) en access 2016 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-gKj36F5R80&t=157s, (min 16:57) pero yo tengo access 2019 y las opciones de macros para tablas, me aparecen desabilitadas, como solucionarlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has mirado la configuración de seguridad en el centro de confianza? Míralo en opciones de Access. Puede ser que estés bloqueando automáticamente cualquier macro

Comment: @Esei Está en Habilitar todas las macros(no recomenado.......)

Comment: ¿Te aparecen deshabilitadas esas opciones incluso en vista diseño? ¿Has probado a abrir la base en modo exclusivo? ¿Es una base antigua mdb o es accdb?

Comment: si, en vista diseño igual. Acabo de intentar en modo exclusivo y tampoco. es una mdb

Comment: Creo que es por ser MDB. Prueba a crear una accdb de cero y mira si te deja meter macros en las tablas ahí. MDB es el formato de compatibilidad para versiones muy antiguas de Access.

Comment: si, con ese cambio, resultó Gracias!!.. lo pones como respuesta para validarlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El formato MDB es el antiguo de bases de datos (versiones de Access anteriores a 2007). Se sigue conservando para situaciones de compatibilidad.

Por otro lado, los triggers en tablas es una funcionalidad nueva disponible únicamente desde Access 2010 en adelante, cuyo formato para trabajar es ACCDB.

Tu archivo es MDB y, por lo tanto, no puede beneficiarse de las funcionalidades nuevas. Si creas un ACCDB sí deberías poder utilizar las macros de eventos en tabla.